# Removing an element who's child element value is 0 through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file which I need to transform with XSLT. In my XSLT file I'm doing a number of things with the xml file. I first copy all elements; then I rename some of the elements. Lastly I need to remove for output any `dealer-code element` that has a `dealer-code-name` of 0. The 1st 2 pieces I have working, but I've tried every piece of code I've found online and can't seem to remove those offending `dealer-code` elements. I'm new to XSLT so I may be doing it all wrong; any help would be appreciated.

Partial xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xmlstructure.xsl"?>
 <AdBaseData>
  <AdBasePreprintInfo FromDistribute="true">
       <PreprintInsert>
        <Sides>2</Sides>
        <PageCount>2</PageCount>
        <InsertSchedule>
            <AdLocInfo>
                <rundates>
                    <date>12042010</date>
                </rundates>
            </AdLocInfo>
            <invoice-text>South Plaza - Stalker Advertisin</invoice-text>
            <BillingOverride Type="Subscriber">49996</BillingOverride>
            <deal-code0>
                <dealer-code-name>A20</dealer-code-name>
                <Delivery-Method Type="Subscriber">
                    <Selected>true</Selected>
                </Delivery-Method>
            </deal-code0>
            <deal-code1>
                <dealer-code-name>0</dealer-code-name>
                <Delivery-Method Type="Subscriber">
                    <Selected>true</Selected>
                </Delivery-Method>
            </deal-code1>
  </InsertSchedule>
</PreprintInsert>
```

My xslt:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'deal-code')]">
       <xsl:element name="dealer-code">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="dealer-code[@dealer-code-name='0']">
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The rename of `deal-code` to `dealer-code` works. However, the last part to not output any `dealer-code-name` with a value of 0 does not. My resulting xml file still lists every `dealer-code` element.

Comment: please use code formatting ({}-button) to format your source code so that we can see it correctly

Comment: Sorry I was fixing as you were viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You do not have any `dealer-code` elements in the source XML. They are `deal-code0` and `deal-code1`
2. `dealer-code-name` is an element, not an attribute.

Your XPATH currently matches `dealer-code` elements with `@dealer-code-name='0'`.  Since there are no `dealer-code` elements and there are no `dealer-code-name` attributes, it never matches and does not suppress the content.

You need to adjust your XPATH to match the `deal-code` elements similar to how you are in the other template and add an additional predicate filter for child elements `dealer-code-name` with a value of 0.  Additionally, since both of your templates have similar matching logic, they may get the same priority level.  You may need to bump up the priority of this redaction template, so that it "wins" against the more generic match:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'deal-code') and dealer-code-name='0']" priority="1"/>
```

Comment: Just tried that. Changed the line to remove the @ before dealer-code-name, ran my file again, and got the same results. My output still has every dealer-code that has a dealer-code-name of 0. I must be missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed other details in your transform and updated my answer.  Your XPATH has two issues preventing it from matching.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. That took care of it. Being new I guess I was assuming there was an order to output so the element would've already been changed to dealer-code before I ran the part to remove names of 0. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that helped. Templates always match on the source XML.  @lweller's solution will also work, but if you can put as much logic in the template match criteria, an XSLT processor has the opportunity to optimize. Might not be a big deal for this scenario, but something to consider for larger files and more complex transforms.

Answer (score 1):

This input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xmlstructure.xsl"?>
<AdBaseData>
  <AdBasePreprintInfo FromDistribute="true">
    <PreprintInsert>
      <Sides>2</Sides>
      <PageCount>2</PageCount>
      <InsertSchedule>
        <AdLocInfo>
          <rundates>
            <date>12042010</date>
          </rundates>
        </AdLocInfo>
        <invoice-text>South Plaza - Stalker Advertisin</invoice-text>
        <BillingOverride Type="Subscriber">49996</BillingOverride>
        <deal-code0>
          <dealer-code-name>A20</dealer-code-name>
          <Delivery-Method Type="Subscriber">
            <Selected>true</Selected>
          </Delivery-Method>
        </deal-code0>
        <deal-code1>
          <dealer-code-name>0</dealer-code-name>
          <Delivery-Method Type="Subscriber">
            <Selected>true</Selected>
          </Delivery-Method>
        </deal-code1>
      </InsertSchedule>
    </PreprintInsert>
  </AdBasePreprintInfo>
</AdBaseData>
```

with this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'deal-code')][dealer-code-name = '0']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the output you're wanting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xmlstructure.xsl"?><AdBaseData>
   <AdBasePreprintInfo FromDistribute="true">
      <PreprintInsert>
         <Sides>2</Sides>
         <PageCount>2</PageCount>
         <InsertSchedule>
            <AdLocInfo>
               <rundates>
                  <date>12042010</date>
               </rundates>
            </AdLocInfo>
            <invoice-text>South Plaza - Stalker Advertisin</invoice-text>
            <BillingOverride Type="Subscriber">49996</BillingOverride>
            <deal-code0>
               <dealer-code-name>A20</dealer-code-name>
               <Delivery-Method Type="Subscriber">
                  <Selected>true</Selected>
               </Delivery-Method>
            </deal-code0>
         </InsertSchedule>
      </PreprintInsert>
   </AdBasePreprintInfo>
</AdBaseData>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'deal-code')]">
     <xsl:if test="dealer-code-name!='0']">
       <xsl:element name="dealer-code">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you have no element `dealer-code` in your input xml, but you can filter when your processing elements starting with `deal-code` by testing if they have a child element `dealer-code-name`which value is 0